# Necromancer Badge description is ambiguous as to what needs a score of 5

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, grammatical-correction

The Badge reads:

> Answer a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

It got me confused, as I expected that I would receive the badge from answering an old question that had 5 or more points. But it seems that you have to give an answer to any old question and get 5 points for your answer.

I just think it could be more well written. The first sentence would be more accurate if it was something like:

> Give an answer with a score of 5 or more to a question with more than 60 days old.

Comment: How do you "Give an answer with 5 points"? Use `•`? I'd say something like: _"Answer a question more than 60 days later and achieve a score of 5 on that answer."_

Comment: @Cerbrus My bad. But you did understand that it should be score.

Comment: Yea, just saying that the wording could be improved :-)

Comment: "Give an answer with a score of 5 or more to a question that is more than 60 days old"

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170809/improve-wording-of-necromancer-badge-to-specify-answer-score-must-be-5) on Meta SE.

Comment: The suggestion is also ambiguous - does one earn the badge when the question gets to be 2 months old? Cerbrus gets closer, but how about "Answer a question more than 60 days later and net a score of 5 or more" - terseness retained, target ambiguity resolved, and no ambiguities introduced.

Comment: "Achieve a score of 5 answering a question that's at least 60 days old."

Comment: Regardless of whether the wording is ambiguous, your interpretation would have allowed anyone to instantly get the badge by posting random crap regardless of merit. It should be obvious that that interpretation isn't going to be right.

Comment: @hvd Instructions should not be left to interpretation.

Comment: @hvd the team wants people to hunt badges because it provides some valuable information to fellow users about their knowledge and their familiarity with the site, and it also drives interaction and high-quality content on the site. If people are trying to earn badges with unclear instructions, that would lead to the opposite: unpredictable and random actions in an attempt to trigger the badge. It's in the site's interest for users to know exactly how a badge is earned.

Comment: @hvd What the team *doesn't* want people to know the details of are quality-control measures, like fraud, spam detection, etc., because they don't want users to know how to circumvent it or fly under the radar.

Comment: @TylerH Please don't read more into my words than I wrote. I didn't write that I think the wording is clear, nor did I write that I think it's okay to leave unclear wording. I only meant, and only wrote, that I think the OP's expectation wasn't reasonable. Since this same suggestion could have equally well been made based on other expectations, my comment says nothing about this suggestion.

Comment: @hvd Sorry, my brain switched your "that that" to "that the" which carried an implication that anyone's interpretation would be off.

Comment: @AaronHall I also think the "later" is a bit ambiguous. Replacing it with "after it was posted" seems better.

Comment: @River I just upvoted kjhughes answer.

Comment: Answer a question 60 days or more after its being asked and obtain a score of 5 or more for your answer.

Comment: Answer a 60+ day old question, obtain a score of 5+ for your answer.

Comment: Clearly the badge page should just contain the SQL query used to award each badge.

Answer (score 63):

I agree that the wording could be improved, but I think we can do better than your initial suggestion.

How's this:

**#1**

> Achieve a score of 5 answering a question that's at least 60 days old.

I think most readers would find that to be clear and unambiguous.

---

Here's a variation intended to address [8bittree's point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346620/necromancer-badge-description-is-ambiguous-as-to-what-needs-a-score-of-5#comment463237_346640), if it's really an issue:

**#2**

> Answer an old question (asked at least 60 days ago) and achieve a score of 5.

Or, even:

**#3**

> Answer a necrotic question (asked at least 60 days ago) and achieve a score of 5.

---

Comment: I agree that my initial suggestion was not the best one. I just opened it to discussion. Your suggestions seems good.

Comment: This makes it clear which item needs to have the score of 5, but I think it takes a step backwards on the clarity of *when* the answer is posted (the initial suggestion has the same issue). In particular, this seems to leave open the interpretation that an score 5 answer given, for example, the day after the question was posted, would grant the necromancer badge 59 days later when the question is 60 days old.

Comment: I dislike #3: the badge name can be fantasist, but the description shouldn't use allegories.

Comment: #2 is good.  #1 does not indicate the answer needed to be initially made after 60 days of posting.

Answer (score 12):

There's a few parts to this description and if we're going to reword it to eliminate the ambiguity of one part, we should be wary of introducing new ambiguity to other parts.

I would propose this:

> Answer a question more than 60 days later and score 5 or more on that answer.

It says:

- What to do (answer a question)
- When to do it (60 days later)
- What score is required (5 or more)
- Which item the score must be on (the given answer)

Comment: For an even simpler change that eliminates ambiguity, we could just append "on that answer" to the existing wording, although it ends up a little longer overall.

Comment: you don't need "_or more_" in the sentence, as the badge is only awarded on score 5, and isn't lost if you subsequently got a score of 4 or 6.

Comment: @Cœur: Are you sure? It's technically possible to go straight from score 4 to score 6, if someone turns a downvote into an upvote. Are you saying the badge is really not awarded in that case?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen oh, good point